# SharePoint framework unit testing pnp

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, pnp-js-core, unit-testing

How can I test with jest a pnp function?
How can I mock the webpart context and pnp responses?

I'm using spfx webpart, pnp-js-core and jest for unit testing

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The SharePoint Framework React Jest Testing sample from GitHub for your reference.

[**SharePoint Framework React Jest Testing sample**](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-jest-testing)

Reference: [SharePoint Framework unit-tests with Jest](https://www.eliostruyf.com/sharepoint-framework-unit-tests-with-jest/)